# Export html table to excel sheet

Tags: c#, html

I have an app that creates and sends an e-mail to my team at work. I create a HTML table dynamically depending on certain conditions. I then use the Outlook HTMLBody method to send my e-mail. The e-mail works fine.

A user has now asked if I can create an html link in the e-mail that will open an excel file showing the same data. My question is there a quick or easy way to copy the html table I'm using for my e-mail straight to excel?

```
 string htmlHeader = "<table style='font-size: 12pt;'><tr><th align='left'>Sedol</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" +
            "<th align='left'>Name</th><th>&nbsp;</th>"+
            "<th align='left'>Ex Date</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" +
            "<th align='left'>Div Type</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" + 
            "<th align='left'>Div Contribution</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" + 
            "<th align='left'>Div Value GBP (p)</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" +
            "<th align='left'>Nominals</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" +
            "<th align='left'>Currency</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" + 
            "<th align='left'>Country of Incorp</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this link for formatting tips: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kaushikborah28/79Nick08302007171404PM/79Nick.aspx

You can add the  tags, and your html should work more or less. The file extension should be probably .xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Since the user asked to be displayed in an excel spreadsheet, you could create a `CSV` file.